# Importing multiple images for machine learning classification

Tags: import, machine-learning

I want to create a ML classifier using images just like [this example](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/highly-automated-machine-learning/distinguish-daytime-from-nighttime-pictures.html).

I have two classes of images in two different folders. Is there an easier way to import all images from both folders rather than inserting picture by picture?

[image]

Comment: something like `Import[#] & /@ FileNames["folder/*.jpg"]` is what you want. Mathematica has about 3 gigabytes of documentation.

Comment: You can also use wildcards directly in `Import`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Classify` actually supports a nice syntax for this:

```
Classify[<|"class1" -> Import["class1/*"], "class2" -> Import["class2/*"]|>]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in order to create your list of images you can use the following piece of code:

```
Join[
 Thread@Rule[Import["~/Desktop/folder1/*.png"], "Day"],
 Thread@Rule[Import["~/Desktop/folder2/*.png"], "Night"]
 ]
```

Of course you will need to change the file path and the properties (day/night) appropriately.

Comment: That `Thread @ Rule` stuff is totally unnecessary. Look at the third usage of `Classify`